# The webOnlyWarmupEngine API is deprecated and will be removed in a future release

Tags: flutter, web

The webOnlyWarmupEngine API is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use `bootstrapEngine` from `dart:ui_web` instead.

The webOnlySetPluginHandler API is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use `setPluginHandler` from `dart:ui_web` instead.

The debugEmulateFlutterTesterEnvironment getter is deprecated and will be removed in a future release.

Please use `debugEmulateFlutterTesterEnvironment` from `dart:ui_web` instead.

---

current local port is http://localhost:65113/

[image]

---

Hello,Im developing app & web code working in app but while I'm trying to run it on web its like something prevent to use internet.
Widgets load successfully but which are internet dependent are not loading

It's my first time on flutter web development and can't understand from where to update this deprecated functions